# Input file accept attribute not working in linux

Tags: html

I am trying to use accept attribute of Input tag to accept only images.

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit">
```

It works fine on windows, but not working on linux.

OS - Fedora 27
Browser - Google Chrome 65.0.3325.181

Comment: Chrome uses the OS MIME type dictionary, and might indeed fail with .match() patterns. Is it able to match `image/jpeg`? One obvious workaround would be to set all the extensions instead e.g `accept="image/*,.bmp,.gif,.png,.svg"` and I probably forgot a lot... https://jsfiddle.net/u45x2qct/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this (accept="image/*,.bmp,.gif,.png,.svg") but its not working. I think problem is with OS.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem under Xubuntu with Vivaldi at the moment.